# Is it better to have/use more credit cards to build credit history/score?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit-score, credit-history

If someone has a credit card with $5,000-$10,000 credit line, and the average amount of monthly payments of this person is around $1500, what is the best scenario for this person to increase their credit history/score? When they can pay all their expenses with only one credit card, is it a good idea for them to apply for more credit cards or try to increase their credit line to maybe achieve more credit history and credit score?

Comment: Why do you want to increase your credit score?

Comment: @JeffUK: To get 0% car loans, home mortgage, etc.

Comment: @ensan3kamel: if credit scores in America work like they do in the UK, [this guide to credit scores](https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/loans/credit-rating-credit-score/#creditrating) is well worth a read, in case you're labouring under any misunderstandings.

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/114696/what-can-i-actually-do-with-a-high-credit-score may be relevant as to why OP would want a better score.

Comment: Depends on how disciplined/sytematic you are. If you are not, dont even think of getting multiple CCs

Answer (score 24):

Increasing the number of cards is a double-edged sword credit-wise. There's a trade-off between the amount of credit used (utilization), number of inquiries and open accounts (fewer is generally better) and *average* length of credit (churning accounts means a shorter average).

The *main* factor in your credit score is a good *payment history*. From what I've seen the number of *made* payments is not significant, but the number of *missed* payments certainly is. So making 10 payments on time is the same as making 1 payment on time, and making 1/10 late payments is just as bad as making 1/1 late payments. So the *danger* of getting many cards is that you lose track of when payments are due (or worse, you overspend and accrue more debt than you can afford), you miss even one, and you've completely negated any positive effect (if any).

In other words, you won't build your credit score much faster by having 10 cards instead of 1, but you can certainly wreck it if you make a mistake.

My advice is to not try and "game the system". Make your payments on time, use credit cards as sparingly as you can (don't spend money just to "get miles"), and your credit score will take care of itself.

Comment: "use credit cards as sparingly as you can" - I would interpret this as "use cash or debit cards whenever possible" (as opposed to "don't spend what you can't afford without debt right now, as far as possible"), but I imagine having a credit card without actually ever using it (the most sparing possible) probably won't help your credit score that much.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: I typically recommend avoiding debit cards entirely for day-to-day purchases.  The fraud protection is better with credit cards (even in cases where is it is on-paper the same).  As for the interest fees: Most credit cards don't charge interest if you pay them in full every month.

Comment: "use credit cards as sparingly as you can" - might be better interpreted as don't go into debt unnecessarily. Some advisors recommend using your credit card for your daily expenditures and paying them off entirely each month. This establishes a borrowing and payment history without creating debt (you had to expend funds anyway for bills, groceries, fuel, etc.).

Comment: @Arluin you can do that _if you can track all of your balances easily and spend less than you make_. The risk is that all of your spending is "hidden" on cards, not coming out of your bank account, making it "seem" like you have more money to spend than you actually do, and can;t pay off the full balances each month. You _can_ do it, but it's very easily to slip into a "debt spiral".

Comment: "Some advisors recommend using your credit card for your daily expenditures and paying them off entirely each month" -- Never do this. If you find yourself in a position where you can't afford that month's expenses, many of them can be "kited" without consequence to the accounts themselves *or* to your credit score. Payment plans can sometimes be negotiated. Using credit to cover recurrent expenditures guarantees you pay interest where late fees might not otherwise exist and reduces your available credit-- which you may find yourself desperately needing in case of a roadside/travel emergency.

Comment: @Ivan "Never do this" - are you saying you should almost never use a credit card at all or are you saying you should never pay off a credit card entirely each month? Or are you saying something else?

Comment: I watch my credit score pretty closely, and there's a strong correlation between usage and score, particularly when usage gets above 10% (OP is at 15-30%), so getting an additional card or two to reduce usage, while it will temporarily reduce your score, should in the long term increase it. That assumes being disciplined of course, getting additional cards and immediately maxing them out will hurt your score, possibly a lot.

Comment: @Ivan I think you're wildly overstating things, and assuming a general lack of discipline on everyone's part. I haven't paid with anything except a credit card in years, and yet have never paid a late fee or cent of interest, so "guarantees you pay interest" is simply wrong. And even at my max usage, still have plenty of credit in case of emergencies. Yes, if someone is going to max a card and pay the minimum, they probably should just have one card they only use often enough to keep open and for real emergencies, but that's not everyone.

Comment: @blm "That assumes being disciplined " that's a big assumption in many cases...

Comment: @Ivan I pay for pretty much everything except utilities, council tax + rent with my credit card. I spend less money that I have available, pay off in full every month via direct debit, and have never paid any interest on it. My peak utilisation is <30%. In fact, over the last year I’ve earned £200 from the cashback. I’m not sure why you’re saying I shouldn’t use my credit card?

Comment: @DStanley Every credit card I ever had had an option where they automatically took the amount at the end of each month without any interaction on my part from my bank account. Obviously you have to have enough money on your bank account for that, but the general guidance is to have at least three months savings that can be easily accessed for obvious reasons, so as long as you do that, there's really nothing that can go wrong. (Now if you have to manually pay the credit card every month that sounds guaranteed to go wrong sooner or later)

Answer (score 4):

Age of accounts, the mix of credit types (revolving, installment, auto, mortgage), utilization rate and payment history are the key metrics of a credit score. If you're using 30% or more of your TOTAL available credit then that hurts your score until you pay it down below 30%.
Every time you add a new card, the average age of accounts declines and affects your score.

As the previous answer said, don't try to game the system.

Comment: It should also be noted that new cards require a hard credit check so your score will drop; albeit insignificantly. However, if you open multiple cards in a 12 month period then that could trigger a big drop.

Comment: I question the utilization wisdom often passed around. Any time I carried so much as a 10% utilization through to my statement date (not payment due date) I would see a hit on my score on various free score services.

Comment: true on both points, @Monkeyzeus.  Same to you, Logarr

Answer (score 1):

To add some info that isn't completely covered in the other answers:

**A big concern I would have in your situation is the utilization percentage**. As the other answers/comments note, >30% will have a significant negative impact, and >10% can have a minor negative impact that might depend on the scoring method. With a limit of $5,000, a $1,500 statement balance would be exactly 30%. With $10,000 you'd still be over 10%.

Even if you're paying that off every month, this could swing your score down depending on when your bank or credit card company sends updates to the scoring bureaus--generally this will be monthly but which day of the month can be hard to determine. As an example, if you had a limit of $5,000 and a balance of $1,501, and your bank reported that as your balance, your score would take a significant hit even if a full payment posted the very next day.

A new card would increase your total limit and help with this issue, but another option is to contact the bank/company of your current card for a limit increase. Every card I've used has the option to request a limit increase without a hard pull every 6 months. You may need to call them to request this, and you'd want to make sure they aren't putting through a hard pull as that would decrease your score temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But when you're just starting to build credit the bank wouldn't trust that for giving you a mortgage loan. Even if you had 20 credit cards with low utilization they would want a lot of other documentation and proof that you're good with money in other areas of your life. So just having 2 cards is fine. When I did it I had 1 recently paid off car loan and 1 card with 2 year history. A card with less history wasn't counted in my favor at all. You're going to need to show other proof that you're credit worthy. The good news is that if you're being responsible it's all pretty easy.

1. 2 years of solid repayment history for at least 2 utility bills.
2. 2 years of solid rent payment history.
3. Reference letter from your landlord.
4. Proof of employment.
5. Proof that your average income over the last 2 years is high enough (tax records or certified accounting books). Basically any income that can't be properly documented does not count.

Now the lender may claim they don't need any of this stuff at first, but eventually, maybe when you least expect it like  2 weeks into a 4 week approval they say, hey we need this one item RIGHT NOW. Zero notice. Then they pull the same thing a few days later. You don't want to get surprised. Document, document, document. Don't expect landlords to keep good paperwork either. Best if you have copies of all your payments with exact dates.